# Backup SQL Server to a Network Share

Tags: sql-server, backup, maintenance

How do you backup an SQL Server Database to a Network Share?

Comment: We don't mind folks answering their own question, but it's generally best practice to actually submit it as an answer, rather than just answering it in the question itself. This allows it to be voted on and evaluated fairly against other people's answers.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the SQL Server Service you're using has access to the network location, you can see a hands-on example of how to backup to a network share in either of the following, free, videos:
[Backups with SQL Server Enterprise Manager](http://www.sqlservervideos.com/sqlserver-backups/backups-with-enterprisemanager)
[Backups with SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.sqlservervideos.com/sqlserver-backups/backups-with-managementstudio)

This video also provides some information on other options and some caveats about backing up to network shares:
[SQL Server Backup Best Practices](http://www.sqlservervideos.com/transcripts/sqlbackup-best-practices)

Answer (score 1):

In order to backup (as part of a schedule SQL Agent Job) to a network share you need to make sure the **SQL Server service**, *and* the **SQL Server Agent service** are running as a Domain account that has access to the destination folder.